# I'm on a next.js project with tailwindcss, but in my src folder I don't have the pages folder and the styles folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, tailwind-css

I am on a next.js project with tailwindcss, but in my src folder I do not have the pages folder and the api subfolder where I have to find the _app.tsx, documents.tsx and index.tsx files, whereas in the tutorial that I am following which dates from 8 months ago there are all these files and folders I nevertheless followed the same procedures what to do in this case?

The global.css file is there which is good, I tried to take the page.tsx file considering it as the index.tsx file, but I can't find 100% the same type of content

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the new Next.js structure after v 13 the `layout.tsx` in your is like `_app.tsx` of old, and `page.tsx` can be used to adjust the content of the layout file. So you should import your `global.css` file in `layout.tsx`, and that should fix your issue mentioned above. I recommend looking more into the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) on this topic.

If you're uncomfortable with the new router structure you could create another Next application and select these options:

[image: Next options]

This will get you the layout that includes `_app.tsx` if you would rather go that route.

Comment: I did it and it worked straight away thank you very much, this problem was starting to bother me

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. Could you mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Next JS has introduced an app router in Next 13. The app router is a little bit different from the page router that we have in older versions. But Next 13 also supports pages router. So you can create a pages directory and create _app and index file or you can create another Next project by selecting pages router to have _app and index as [Derek Glassick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626952/16981097) mentioned.

You can learn more about the app router and structure at [Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure).

[image]